# Spring Security with two databases H2 in memory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am trying accesing to my console H2 localhost:8080/h2-console, but it doesn't work.

I am using spring boot (V 3.0.2)

The problem showes up when i try to access the second h2 datasource or try to access the console path because it can not decide what H2CONSOLE.PROPERTIES to use.

My security config is:

package com.queueup.security;

```
    import com.queueup.security.filters.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
    import com.queueup.security.filters.JwtAuthorizationFilter;
    import com.queueup.security.jwt.JwtUtils;
    import com.queueup.security.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
    import static org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest.toH2Console;
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {
    
        @Autowired
        JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    
        @Autowired
        UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    
        @Autowired
        JwtAuthorizationFilter authorizationFilter;
    
        @Bean
        SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
    
            JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JwtAuthenticationFilter(jwtUtils);
            jwtAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            jwtAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");
    
            return httpSecurity
                    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                        auth.requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll();
                        auth.requestMatchers("/hello").permitAll();
                        auth.requestMatchers("/createUser").permitAll();
                        auth.requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();
                        auth.requestMatchers("/api/path/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER");
                        auth.requestMatchers("/api/path1/**").hasRole("USER");
                        auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                    })
                    .sessionManagement(session -> {
                        session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                    })
                    .addFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter)
                    .addFilterBefore(authorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .build();
        }
    
    //    @Bean
    //    UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
    //        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    //        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("santiago")
    //                .password("1234")
    //                .roles()
    //                .build());
    //
    //        return manager;
    //    }
    
        @Bean
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
       }
    
        @Bean
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) throws Exception {
            return httpSecurity.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                    .and().build();
        }
    }`
```

My datasource config is:

```
package com.queueup;

import com.queueup.config.DataSourcesConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.queueup.repositories.enqueuers",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "enqueueUpEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "enqueueupTransactionManager")
public class PersistenceEnqueueupConfiguration {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:enqueueupdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ENQUEUEUP";

    public PersistenceEnqueueupConfiguration(){
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource enqueueUpDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DataSourcesConfig.H2DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(URL);
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean enqueueUpEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(enqueueUpDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.queueup.entities");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
                = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
               "create-drop");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                DataSourcesConfig.H2DIALECT);
        properties.put("dataSourceClassName",
                DataSourcesConfig.H2DRIVER);
        properties.put("h2.console.enabled",
                false);
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", false);
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", false);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager enqueueupTransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                enqueueUpEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.queueup;

import com.queueup.config.DataSourcesConfig;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;

import static org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest.toH2Console;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.queueup.repositories.security",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "userEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "userTransactionManager")
public class PersistenceUsersConfiguration {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:userdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS USERS";

    public PersistenceUsersConfiguration(){
        super();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource userDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DataSourcesConfig.H2DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(URL);
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(userDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.queueup.security.models");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
                = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                "create-drop");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                DataSourcesConfig.H2DIALECT);
        properties.put("dataSourceClassName",
                DataSourcesConfig.H2DRIVER);
        properties.put("h2.console.enabled",
                true);
        properties.put("h2.console.path", toH2Console());
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", false);
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", false);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager userTransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                userEntityManager().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

if i try to access the console i got 403 forbidden and when i try to execute the second datasources ( in any order) i got

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleProperties'
```

but i if remove the

```
auth.requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll();
```

this line it works but i can access the console. The problem is because spring doesn't know what instance use.

I define one bean more for trying to solution it, but, if well i don't get the error i can access the console.

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@Configuration
public class H2ConsolePropConfig {

    private final H2ConsoleProperties h2ConsoleProperties;

    public H2ConsolePropConfig(){
        h2ConsoleProperties = new H2ConsoleProperties();

        h2ConsoleProperties.setEnabled(true);
        h2ConsoleProperties.setPath("/h2-console");
        h2ConsoleProperties.getSettings().setWebAdminPassword("");
        h2ConsoleProperties.getSettings().setWebAllowOthers(true);
        h2ConsoleProperties.getSettings().setTrace(true);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public H2ConsoleProperties getH2ConsoleProperties() {
        return h2ConsoleProperties;
    }
}
```

Maybe if i would know how can inject it in my primary datasource I could make it go.

If you could help me, i will be grateful.

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

**Let see what is the problem is :**

- By default spring query to default/primary database

**How we can fix it :**

- We need to change default database on the fly
- Consider you have 2 in memory db one for students and one for members

**Steps :**

- define below enum

```
public enum AuthServerDatabase {
    CLIENT_DB_STUDENT, CLIENT_DB_MEMBER
}
```

- define below class for set and get default database context

```
public class AuthServerDatabaseContextHolder {
    private static ThreadLocal<AuthServerDatabase> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void set(AuthServerDatabase clientDatabase) {
        Assert.notNull(clientDatabase, "clientDatabase cannot be null");
        CONTEXT.set(clientDatabase);
    }

    public static AuthServerDatabase getClientDatabase() {
        return CONTEXT.get();
    }

    public static void clear() {
        CONTEXT.remove();
    }

}
```

- override below method

```
public class AuthServerSourceRouter extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return AuthServerDatabaseContextHolder.getClientDatabase();
    }
}
```

- write below db configuration

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {

    public DataSource studentDataSource()
    {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url(" your db connection ur");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("your db username");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("your db password");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
    public DataSource membersDataSource()
    {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url(" your db connection ur");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("your db username");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("your db password");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource clientDatasource()
    {
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        DataSource studentDB = studentDataSource();
        DataSource membersDB = membersDataSource();
        targetDataSources.put(AuthServerDatabase.CLIENT_DB_STUDENT, studentDB);
        targetDataSources.put(AuthServerDatabase.CLIENT_DB_MEMBER, membersDB);

        AuthServerSourceRouter clientRoutingDatasource = new AuthServerSourceRouter();
        clientRoutingDatasource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        clientRoutingDatasource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(studentDB);
        return clientRoutingDatasource;
    }
}
```

- now on the fly set your db selection and clear i.e set to default/primary

> AuthServerDatabaseContextHolder.set(AuthServerDatabase.CLIENT_DB_MEMBER);
>
> // your query or business logic associated to member database
>
> AuthServerDatabaseContextHolder.clear();

Comment: @Charlie good day, i did not update SecurityConfig as in your comment "if remove the
auth.requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll();
this line it works". could you pls tell what further issue you are facing

Comment: Hi Sahab, if we are using OAUTH2 for access h2 console in Spring 3.0.2 you need to add  "if remove the auth.requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll()" otherwise you will not have authorization and it wll not work. I think your solution could be work, but i need to know how could i keep the rest of my datasources codes with its entityManagerFactory and TransactionManagerMethod.  
The problem is H2CONSOLEPROPERTIES it couldn't choose what h2console datasource to use.

Comment: hi Charlie for authorization you need to give access from jwtAuthenticationFilter based on jwt token you receive form request. For database jpa query try to select table form default db you set and if it not found there then it look for repo table to other db inside application

Comment: you can use below code inside your jwtAuthenticationFilter once jwt token is valid 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetailsService,
                    null
            );
            authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);